# How can I speed up Rails unit tests involving image upload/resizing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, paperclip, testunit

My app does a lot with images. I use paperclip to attach them to models. I have tons of tests (Test::Unit) that involve creating images, these run pretty slowly.

I use FactoryGirl to create models in my tests. This is how I create image attachments:

```
factory :product_image_100_100 do
    image File.new(File.join(::Rails.root.to_s, "/test/fixtures/images", "100_100.jpg"))
end
```

How can I fake the image upload or otherwise speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

[This snippet](http://trevorturk.com/2009/03/12/speeding-up-paperclip-tests-by-a-lot/) worked for me:

```
require 'test_helper'
class PhotoTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    Paperclip::Attachment.any_instance.stubs(:post_process).returns(true)
  end

  # tests...
end
```

**Upd.** My current preference is to stub out ImageMagic globally, by adding the following to my test_helper.rb:

```
module Paperclip
 def self.run(cmd, *)
   case cmd
   when "identify"
     return "100x100"
   when "convert"
     return
   else
     super
   end
 end
end
```

(Adapted from [here](http://wayneye.com/Blog/12-Tips-To-Boost-RSpec-And-Cucumber) – btw, you may want to take a look at this article if you're interested in speeding up your tests)